# Collision handler not detecting correctly libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using a 2d boolean array for detecting collision. The collision detection works flawlessly for my players collision however, when the Spell object collision detection checks it always detects true. Where my player stands and below him, everything is true but above that is false. It's like Terraria, pretty much everything below you is true in the beginning. However when my spells are in the air, they are detecting true. Here is the code for detecting collision with the ground, it checks if where the spell in the `spellList` grid position is and if it is true.

```
    public void update(){
    this.spellList = player.getSpells();
    for(int i = 0; i < spellList.size(); i++){
        if(grid.getGrid()[(int) spellList.get(i).getGridPosition().x]
                [(int) spellList.get(i).getGridPosition().y]){
            spellList.get(i).react();
            System.out.println("true");
        }else
            System.exit(0);
    }
```

This seems fool proof however in the following image the spell returns true and `System.exit(0);` never is called. You can tell what is true because there is a white box outlining it. 
[Examplle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUa2I.png)

I am not sure why the spells react method is being called when that grid position isn't true

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean with "I am not sure why the spells react method is returning true". if `spellList.get(i).react();` returns something, you never check it. For your `grid.getGrid()[x][y]` sure its the correct order of x and y? Is it the same grid as in your player check? Etc...

Comment: Can you show `grid` and how do you draw your tiles? I ask this since it is easy to either swap x and y or y and -y, etc..